# Wrapping C++ function with Mapped SparseMatrix input using eigency (cython)

Tags: python, c++, cython, eigen

I am a newbie in Cython and C++ in need of a Cython example for using [Eigen::SparseMatrix](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__Sparse__chapter.html) through [eigency](https://github.com/wouterboomsma/eigency)

[eigency tests](https://github.com/wouterboomsma/eigency/tree/master/tests/eigency_tests) have been very helpful for interfacing my C++ code with Python. However, they only have dense matrix examples.

I would like to use map Python data type to Eigen::SparseMatrix for computation in C++

Are there any experts that can help me implement a modification of [this example function](https://github.com/wouterboomsma/eigency/blob/205efc54b747f660bfd211e0040d793eed70b0d7/tests/eigency_tests/eigency_tests_cpp.cpp#L26) to use SparseMatrix?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Based on a quick look, it doesn't seem like eigency has wrapped anything to do with sparse matrices. So the answer is likely "you can't"

Comment: Maybe you can ask on eigency, create an issue. They may have more info on that :)

Comment: @Sant, I would agree with @DavidW. You would first need to implement the wrapping functions for sparse matrices in `eigency` before being able to use them within Cython